Can any expert help me please? in poke faces
Can any expert help me please?
Lately i switched to blender from another software, really impressed what it can offer especially with its powerful addons, however i am still facing some issues.
i will try to make it a simple question:
if i want to make a torus with a poke edges only.
in the last software i was able to do it in 4 easy steps:
Create a torus, select All edges, poke edges, Dissolves selected edges
so it ends with a torus with a diagonal edges only, Hope the attached images can help.
Anyone know how to do this in blender?
i can't select or store selection of edges, even as vertex group, if i create poke faces i can't select the ring edges.
Any idea how to solve this please?




Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "help me with","issue with" or "question about". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See "What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

In Edit mode, Select All and then use the Face > Poke Faces menu to give this result:

In Vertex mode, select one of the original vertices and then use Select > Select Similar > Amount of Connecting Edges:

Switch to Edge mode with the vertices still selected, right-click and select Dissolve Edges:

to give this result:


Thank you so much John for you help.

You're welcome. Thanks for marking the answer as correct.
